# Prestashop - Change template product list for custom mail

Tags: email, templates, prestashop

I'm started using Prestashop since few days and I would like to change the template product list in :

my_project -> mails -> _partials -> order_conf_product_list.tpl

I have created my own mail theme and I see in **PaymentModule.php** the *getEmailTemplateContent()* method who search the order_conf_product_list.tpl but I don't know how overwrite it.

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.7.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but you need to store **order_conf_product_list.tpl** on this path:

```
YOUR_THEME/mails/YOUR_LANGUAGE/order_conf_product_list.tpl
```